# CUE sheet, Daemon Tools Lite and VLC media player = issue

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

VLC Medial Player doesn't display CD-TEXT correctly. No matter how hard I try, second song title defined after the main one (typically two songs in one track, or two names for the same song), the second name is displayed as performer instead of song title. That applies for brackets, slash and dash delimiter.

Here's how VLC Media Player sees the track list:
[image: How VLC sees the tracks]

And here's how it's actually defined:
[image: How it's actually defined]

My question is - how can I display it correctly with VLC Media Player? The only one other media player I have, is actually Windows Media Player that doesn't know CD-TEXT at all and therefore doesn't display any names. Groove Player is beyond my understanding and takes a loong time to launch, which is unacceptable.

Comment: Okay, I just managed to somehow launch Groove Music, just to know it doesn't even support Audio CD format :D :D Well, another useless program I have here :D :D

Comment: Okay, nevermind. Windows Media Player with WMPCDTEXT extension displays it correctly (and even displays cover art downloaded from Internet) :)

Comment: So I'm going to report a bug to VLC devs, apparently...